# how can i fit image to square and center it vertically and horizontally

Tags: css

Did try already several flex arguments but none of them worked like selg-align and self-content.
So the idea is the fit the image to the square and center it vertically and horizontally...
Does anybody can help with this  thanks...

I am unsure of the why i need to edit this topic... it's just a simple question on how to fit the image in the square and center it vertically and horizontally (obvious to such square)... Don't understand where is the confusion about the question...

My examples is at https://jsfiddle.net/ej3814sn/

```
.five {
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.five-a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
}

.five-b {
    float: right;
    color: white;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check my answer then leave a comment..

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor i am sure thats not what OP meant by vertically and horizontally. But lets see.

Comment: @user3801128 i update my answer ..

Comment: thanks for everyone help and for the fast reply. I would validate as well the @AbdullahAlNoor answer to (after the edit) but it seems i can only validate one and i feel like the one from Always Helping better.

Comment: @user3801128 Glad to help you. Happy coding. Let me know if i can help any further :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `img` in a `div` and outside of `five` - Using `float` is **not** a good idea at all in modern browsers.

Use `flex` to achieve your desired `results` and it is very **responsive** in modern `browsers` as well. Also set the `height` of `.one` to `auto` make sure `img` always `centered` and below the numbers.

**Live Demo:**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #232323;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.two {
  width: 50%;
}

.four {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.five {
  height: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.five-a {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.five-b {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}

.img-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*fit image to the square and center it*/
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">
      <div id="tree">
        <div id="0" class="four">
          <div class="five">
            <div class="five-a">1</div>
            <div class="five-b">10</div>
          </div>
          <div class="img-div">
            <img src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/whatsapp-logo-1-1.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, to position elements, is to use `position` property. Notice that I have made a change in HTML code as well. Put the image out of `five` element. Now talking about CSS, position both `img` and `five` as `absolute`. You would have to set `top` to `0`, `width` to `100%` for `five`. And for `img`, just set `self-align` to `center`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #232323;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.two {
  width: 50%;
}

.four {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.five {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.five-a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.five-b {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  align-self: center;
}


/*fit image to the square and center it*/
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">
      <div id="tree">
        <div id="0" class="four">
          <div class="five">
            <div class="five-a">1</div>
            <div class="five-b">10</div>
          </div>
          <img src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/whatsapp-logo-1-1.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to center the image in the `.five` div, yes?
EDIT: Remove the image tag and place your image as a background of the element you wish to center it in... Then add `no-repeat`, 0% to `position` and set the bg size to `100%`, however change the height of the element to `100%` as well...

```css
.five {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/whatsapp-logo-1-1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #232323;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.two {
  width: 50%;
}

.four {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.five {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/whatsapp-logo-1-1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.five-a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.five-b {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/*fit image to the square and center it*/
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div id="tree">
      <div id="0" class="four">
        <div class="five">
          <span class="five-a">1</span>
          <span class="five-b">10</span>
          <img src="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```